# Why does using flatMap with an async function not return a flatten array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flatmap

I want to understand why using `.flatMap()` with `async` does not return a flatten array.

For example, for Typescript, this returns an array of numbers:
*I know `Promisse.all` and `async` are useless with a simple array of number, it is just easier for reproduction*

```
const numbers = [[1], [2], [3]];
// typed as number[]
const numbersFlatten = await Promise.all(
    numbers.flatMap((number) => number),
);
```

When this, for Typescript, returns an array of array of numbers (just added an async) :

```
const numbers = [[1], [2], [3]];
// typed as number[][]
const numbersFlatten = await Promise.all(
    numbers.flatMap(async (number) => number),
);
```

Comment: Does it *actually return* a different result, or does something just statically infer the wrong type…?!

Answer (score 11):

All [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions implicitly return Promises. By making your [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) callback `async`, it now returns a Promise that resolves to the `number` from your array. For `.flatMap()` to work correctly and for it to flatten its results, the callback should return an array, not a Promise. Below is an example of the problematic behaviour:

```js
const numbers = [[1], [2], [3]];
const promiseAllArg = numbers.flatMap(async (number) => number); // same as `.flatMap(number => Promise.resolve(number))`, flatMap doesn't know how to flatten `Promise<number>` into a resulting array
console.log(promiseAllArg); // [Promise<[1]>, Promise<[2]>, Promise<[3]>]
```

Instead, you can use a regular [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call to obtain a nested array of resolved values followed by a [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) call:

```js
(async () => {
  const numbers = [[1], [2], [3]];
  const awaitedNumbers = await Promise.all(
    numbers.map(async (number) => number) // some async code
  );
  const numbersFlattened = awaitedNumbers.flat() // flatten the resolved values
  console.log(numbersFlattened);
})();
```

Comment: That is what I did, but I do not understand why the Promises could not be flatten in an array !

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959270/why-does-using-flatmap-with-an-async-function-not-return-a-flatten-array#comment132279982_74959389) "_why the Promises could not be flatten in an array_": @maximeSurmontSO to **flatten** an array means to concatenate sub-array elements. Because promises are not arrays, they cannot be flattened. See: [`Array.prototype.flat()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: @maximeSurmontSO Also a promise doesn't necessarily have value in it. It's an object that could be in a pending state at the time `.flatMap()` creates its array (meaning it "holds" no value yet). It's only sometime in the future when the promise might change to a resolved state where it then holds a certain value. For `.flatMap()` to work correctly with Promises, it would internally need to wait for each to resolve and then merge the resolved values into its resulting array,  which it doesn't do (as `.flatMap()` is not asynchronous). Internally, it only flattens arrays into its final result

Comment: I get it now, thanks ! It really "just" chains a `.map()` and a `.flat()`, so yeah `.flat()` is not working with an array of promises but with a promise of an array of promises, which it does not handle

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that the fact `Promise` is eager also has performance implications.

```js
const asyncFlatMap = <A, B>(arr: A[], f: (a: A) => Promise<B>) =>
    Promise.all(arr.map(f)).then(arr => arr.flat());

asyncFlatMap([[1], [2], [3]], async nums => nums); // Promise<number[]>
```

You can see in the code above that we need to `map`, then `flat`, with this additional round trip through the microtasks queue because of the `then` in-between. Doing this kind of round trip for the sake of playing Lego is wasteful.

Note that if you don't write an `asyncFlatMap` helper you can avoid that `then` of course. I'm making a general statement here.

If you happen to nest promises a lot you may be interested in [Fluture](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture).

Futures are lazy, so you can play Lego with them before anything is run.

```js
import { resolve, parallel, promise, map } from 'fluture';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';

const numbersFlatten = await pipe(
    numbers.map(nums => resolve(nums)), // Future<number[]>[]
    parallel(10), // Future<number[][]>
    map(x => x.flat()), // Future<number[]>
    promise // Promise<number[]>
);
```

In the code above I converted the Future back to a Promise with `promise` in order to match your use case. It is only when this function is called that the computation is run. `fork` would also run the computation without ever involving promises.

In case you are not familiar with `pipe`: the first argument is the value which is threaded through the remaining function arguments.

The magic value `10` in `parallel` is just the maximum number of computations to run concurrently. It could have been anything else.